# Terraform - self.default_ip_address / ipv4_address missmatch

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I have some annoying problem here.

I am trying to use file and remote-exec provisioners when creating (Windows) VM-s with Terraform.

Please see my template (this is only for a VM, I separated it from the variables and the core infrastructure for now) here: https://code.prkr.li/60463d5e2b38ad032b4b6678

The only thing that does not work presently is using the self.default_ip_address as a host for the provisioner's connection. The task (as seen in the Terraform logs in Jenkins) tries to connect to the IP address that the VM got from DHCP...

[image]

...instead of what is defined in the (customization) config...

[image]

So I suppose viable solutions would be:

- refreshing the default IP
- using hostname (not sure if that is possible, did not manage to find the right syntax)
- ???

Any ideas / suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

Not that there were a lot of answers, but I found my solution apparently.
Anyone having similar issue, suggested to use

```
host = self.clone.0.customize.0.network_interface.0.ipv4_address
```

Workes for me anyway.